# I have copied a code from html template and modified it accordingly to react and did same with css but somehow my main component isn't picking up css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
import './App.css';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard.js';

function App() {
  return (
      <Dashboard />
  );
}

export default App;
```

> I have copied the html code in Dashboard.js and same with css file which I copied in app.css ,   I have modified both css and js html code accordingly to react. There are no errors compile time
> or run time. It just doesn't picks up code. Please tell me what could be the problem here .

> One correction -: my css file is connecting with js file as I can see few of my css codes are running but only 2-3 css lines are running , rest are not.
> I guess its issue related to difference between normal html css and react html css. I have copied html code of a normal html css bootstrap template and same done with css file too. I changed much of the code according to react rules but I guess still something I'm forgetting which I'm not able to figure out. I'm just feeling something is wrong related to classnames which I'm using to address into css codes. Please look into my js and css file where I'm going wrong.
> I have uploaded Dashboard.js , Dashboard.css and App.js in git
> Please check here - https://github.com/Agent00XX/test-react

Comment: does your `<Dashboard/>` internal HTML components have the same css as it's available in `App.css`? Or, have you opened the correct URL in the browser?

Comment: Share your Dashboard.js contents.

Comment: also share your snippet from dashboard and css file

Comment: I have explained situation check above. and share link to my files. Help will be very much appreciated

Comment: Are the three files in the repo the only ones? Try creating a new project with [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app) and pasting your js and css files there.

Comment: No, I have a full react app files create-react-app, I only uploaded those on git because issue is with the dashboard.js and its css file only

Comment: are classes syntax like page-header allowed in react css or its should be written as page_header ??